# Can you configure AWS Console for your time zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a maintenance event coming up on our EC2 servers, and the AWS Console lists the event time in UTC-5 - which is US Eastern.

> **Start time** September 26, 2014 7:00:00 AM UTC-5

Our company is not in this time zone (we're in Central), nor is it the time zone of our instances (Oregon/us-west-2). So having time listed in UTC-5 is slightly confusing.

Is there any preference somewhere that we can set our preferred time zone so we don't have to do the math ourselves?

(I know this is picky and if it happens enough we'll just get used to it, but when it comes to scheduled reboots of our instances I'd rather everything be crystal clear to all team members)

Comment: But that IS Central time! Remember you're currently in Daylight Saving Time

Comment: Haha, you're right! Whoops.

Comment: It is not possible yet, but there is a feature request for this [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=79653).

Comment: My problem was that it was hard to correlate EC2 console showing UTC times with Cloudwatch metric graphs showing local browser’s times. As mentioned in one of the forum threads referred to in the comments below, in Cloudwatch one can click on the ‘custom’ option from the time ranges on the top right. See under “To change the dashboard time format” here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/change_dashboard_time_format.html

Answer (score 2):

Open the CloudWatch console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/.

In the navigation pane, choose Dashboards and select a dashboard.

Choose custom.

From the upper corner, choose UTC or Local timezone.

Comment: This works in log groups view as well. That is, set the time zone in the Custom date range search area.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not allowed by now:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=135147

Comment: That's specific to one portion of the console.

Comment: See also https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=79653

Comment: @YvesM. Interesting to see this was asked 7 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid **configuring** the timezone is not supported. However, [the provider documents that it can be **changed**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/change_dashboard_time_format.html). I see no way to make that change a permanent configuration.
Note that as of February 2024, the documentation must be outdated. There is no need to click *Custom* for the dropdown to show. Also note that you won't find these controls in any dashboard, only those with time date, like All metrics.